# Sending raw ZPL to Zebra printer without using any of their proprietary software via CLI

Tags: python, zebra-printers

I would like to send raw ZPL to my printer Zebra GK420t via some script, ideally Python or shell, or just Windows terminal. I do not want to use any of their proprietary software, because the process needs to be automated. I am connected to my printer via USB connection, namely the USB001 port. Everything I have found so far relates to sending data through LAN, or doing it through Zebra software, but nothing where I could write a script and send the raw command myself through USB.

Comment: The .Net SDK does have a command line option. You said you wanted to avoid proprietary software for automation reasons. Not sure if that is your only reason, but if it is the command line should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do that works 100% (Windows only):

```
1. Add a new Generic/Text Only printer (let's say name is BARCODEPRINTER) in the Devices and Printers (use the defaults and make sure to select the correct USB port)
2. Create your ZEBRA script in Notepad
3. Print and select BARCODEPRINTER
```

If Windows gives an error saying "Paper too small to print one time...", do the following:

```
1. Share the printer.
2. Open a DOS command prompt
3. Redirect the output of the printer to LPT2 or to any available port: NET USE LPT2 \\IP ADDRESS OF YOUR PC\BARCODEPRINTER
4. Still in command prompt, go to the folder where you saved your ZEBRA script file.
5. Copy the file to LPT2. COPY <NAME OF ZEBRA SCRIPT FILE> LPT2
```

You can now do changes to your script and see the changes immediately.